# One sided trig identity with conjugates $\frac{(\cos x\cot x)}{\cot x-\cos x}=\frac{\cot x+\cos x}{(\cos x\cot x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been given a trigonometric identity worksheet. We need to use conjugates to solve these identities. One sided proofs. I've spent some time on it but just can't crack it. Here it is, help appreciated. Any tips (such as which side to start on etc) is appreciated.

$$\frac{(\cos x\cot x)}{\cot x-\cos x}=\frac{\cot x+\cos x}{(\cos x\cot x)}$$

Comment: Hint: use conjugation on either side. Notice symmetry.

Comment: I tried applying (cotx+cosx) to the left side and got a few steps in, though I wasn't able to finish it up.

Answer (score 3):

As $\cos x=\cot x\cdot\sin x$ for $\sin x\ne0,$

$$(\cot x+\cos x)(\cot x-\cos x)=\cot^2x\left(1-\sin^2x\right)=?$$

Answer (score 1):

For $\sin x\neq0$,

$\dfrac{(\cos x\cot x)}{\cot x-\cos x}=\dfrac{(\cos x\cot x)}{\cos x(\csc x-1)}=\dfrac{\cot x}{\csc x-1}\cdot\dfrac{\csc x+1}{\csc x+1}=\dfrac{\csc x\cot x+\cot x}{\cot^2x}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}+\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}}{\dfrac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2 x}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\cos x+\sin x\cos x}{\sin^2 x}}{\dfrac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2 x}}={\dfrac{\cos x+\sin x\cos x}{\sin^2 x}}\cdot{\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}}={\dfrac{\cos x+\sin x\cos x}{\sin x}}\cdot{\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}}=\left(\cot x+\cos x\right)\dfrac{1}{\cos x\cot x}=\dfrac{\cot x+\cos x}{(\cos x\cot x)}$

Comment: It should be $\sin x\ne0\iff x\ne m\pi$ for any integer $n$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Yeah. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Could you outline the final step a bit more? Are you using that a/b/c = a*c/b rule?

Comment: Yes but prior to that taking lcm in the numerator. $\dfrac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}=\dfrac{a\cdot d}{b\cdot c}$.

Comment: Sorry, I tried working that out but still couldn't figure out how the full transition of the final step. Could you expand the answer itself some more steps, skipping the lcm part?

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\cos x\cot x}{\cot x-\cos x}=\cdots=\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}$$

Similarly simplify the right hand side

Finally use $$\cos^2x=(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)$$

$$\implies\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}=?$$

Alternatively, $$\dfrac{\cot x-\cos x}{\cot x\cos x}=\dfrac1{\cos x}-\dfrac1{\cot x}=\sec x-\tan x$$

which is $=\dfrac1{\sec x+\tan x}=?$